# How do I make the iframe(child) from another iframe(parent) bigger than the its parent?

Tags: php, fancybox

I'm creating a Purchase Order form in PHP and Fancybox and I'm having a hard time making a UI wherein inside a page the user can select a supplier and then after that a hyperlink will appear that will allow the user to add an item and once clicked another modal window is shown where a form containing the list of items are displayed as well as the quantity.

I was already able to do all the php coding correctly my problem now is that once I open the first Iframe the second Iframe becomes very small(which is what is expected because of the script 'width' and 'height'). Is there a way to work around this?

I already know how to get back to the previous iframe, I did that by adding a submit button with a form action="mypage".

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help. Thank you.